# Storing a line in a variable

Tags: shell, variables, awk

Hi I have the following batch script where I submitted each file to a separate processing as follows:

```
for file in ../Positive/*.txt_rn; do
bsub <<EOF
#BSUB -L /bin/bash
#BSUB -W 150:00
#BSUB -M 10000
#BSUB -n 3
#BSUB -e /somefolder/errors/%J.err
#BSUB -o /somefolder/errors/%J.out
  while read line; do
  name=`cat \$line | awk '{print $1":"$2"-"$3}'`
  four=`cat \$line | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d\: -f4`
  fasta=\$name".fa"
  op=\$name".rs"
  echo \$name | xargs samtools faidx /somefolder/rn4/Rattus_norvegicus/UCSC/rn4/Sequence/WholeGenomeFasta/genome.fa > \$fasta
  Process -F \$fasta -M "list_"\$four".txt" -p 0.003 | awk '(\$5 >= 0.67)' > \$op
 if [ -s "\$op" ]
   then
cat "\$line" >> ../Positive_Strand/$file".cons"
fi
rm \$lne
rm \$op
rm \$fasta
done < $file
EOF
done
```

I am am somehow unable to store the values of the column from the line (which is in `$line` variable into the `$name` and `$four` variable and hence unable to carry on further processes. Also any suggestions to edit the code for a better version of it would be welcome.

Comment: Add `set -x` to the script and see what is executing at each point. That might help you find the problem.

Comment: I don't understand how that is to be done

Comment: That's a command. You just put it near the top of the script. It will spit out a bunch of "debugging" output about the commands that the shell runs.

Comment: Thanks will try that!

Comment: Try to make a simple script first (only `date>/tmp/bsub.out`) and add lines. Are you sure you want a for loop over one file (the file  ../Positive/.txt_rn) ?

Comment: I am sorry I corrected the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `EOF` to `'EOF'` then you will more properly disable shell interpretation.  Your problem is that your back-ticks (`` ` ``) are not escaped.

I've fixed your indentation and cleaned up some of your code.  Note that the syntax highlighting here doesn't understand `cat <<'EOF'`.  If you paste that into `vim` with highlighting enabled, you'll see that block is all the same color since it's just a string.

```sh
bsub_helper() {
  cat <<'EOF'
#BSUB -L /bin/bash
#BSUB -W 150:00
#BSUB -M 10000
#BSUB -n 3
#BSUB -e /somefolder/errors/%J.err
#BSUB -o /somefolder/errors/%J.out
  while read line; do
    name=`cat $line | awk '{print $1":"$2"-"$3}'`
    four=`cat $line | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d: -f4`
    fasta="$name.fa"
    op="$name.rs"
    genome="/somefolder/rn4/Rattus_norvegicus/UCSC/rn4/Sequence/WholeGenomeFasta/genome.fa"
    echo $name | xargs samtools faidx "$genome" > "$fasta"
    Process -F "$fasta" -M "list_$four.txt" -p 0.003 | awk '($5 >= 0.67)' > "$op"
    if [ -s "$op" ]
    then
      cat "$line" >> "../Positive_Strand/$file.cons"
    fi
    rm "$lne" "$op" "$fasta"
EOF
  echo "  done < \"$1\""
}

for file in ../Positive/*.txt_rn; do
  bsub_helper "$file" |bsub
done
```

I created a helper function because I needed to get the input in two commands.  I am assuming that `$file` is the only variable in that block that you want interpreted.  I also surrounded that variable (among others) with quotes so that the code can support file names with spaces in them.  The final line of the helper has nested double quotes for this reason.

I left your `echo $name | xargs …` line alone because it's so odd.  Without quotes around `$name`, `xargs` will take each whitespace-separated entry as its own file.  With quotes, `xargs` will only supply one (likely invalid) file name to `samtools`.

If `$name` is a *single* file, try:

```sh
samtools faidx "$genome" "$name" > "$fasta"
```

If `$name` is *multiple* files *and none of them have spaces*, try:

```sh
samtools faidx "$genome" $name > "$fasta"
```

The only reason to use `xargs` here would be if you have too much content for one command line, but if you're running `echo $name | xargs` then you'll run into the same problem.